# Shmget: Invalid argument. Why i get this error?

Tags: c, memory, pointers, shared

I get a "shmget: Invalid argument error" while i try to execute this part of code

```
  int *nFS, *spb, *cell1, shmid;
  key_t key = 5768; 

  //i need a shared memory segment in which i can put 3 ints
  if ((shmid = shmget(key, (sizeof(int) * 3), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0 ) {
             perror("shmget");
             exit(1);
       } 
 if ((spb = (int)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0))== -1 ){  
            perror("shmat");
            exit(1);
      }
  cell1= spb + 1 ;
  nFS= cell1 + 1;
  //i try to assign here 7 to  nFS
  *nFS=7;
```

there is something wrong here but i can't figure out what. Can you help me?

Thanks, Alex.

Comment: someone who has a problem like yours [cboard](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/19990-shmget-function.html)

Comment: You're asking for too little!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the shmget(1) man page:

> EINVAL A  new segment was to be created and size < SHMMIN or size >
>   SHMMAX, or no new segment was to be
>                 created, a segment with given key existed, but size is greater than the size of that segment.

You should check whether you still have an segment for this key using `ipcs` and remove it with `ipcrm`.

Comment: can i use a different way to assign a value to key in order to get a bigger space of available memory?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the value of the `size_t __size` parameter was less than 0.
For reference, `shmget()` is prototyped as:

`int shmget(key_t __key, size_t __size, int __shmflg)`